# How do I prevent React Native Flatlist hiding items on Android (when Im trying to stack them)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Despite what I believe to be expected, Flatlist seems to be trying to performance manage my items, when I'm trying to stack them upon each other on Android. It works fine on iOS.

I'm trying to use Flatlist (rightly or wrongly - feel free to judge) to easily render a stack of SVGs on top of each other to created a layered view (which I eventually export to a PNG). However on Android, when I negative margin or absolute/relative position each item so they start from the same point, they don't get rendered on Android.

I've tested this and if they don't perfectly align, I get a scrollview and when I touch it, the 2nd item in the view appears.

Here's a code snippet:

```
      <View style={styles.previewContainerStyle}>
          <FlatList ref={previewRef}
            data={featureLookups}
            style={styles.previewListStyle}
            renderItem={({item, index}) =>
              <View style={[styles.previewItemStyle, {marginTop: -1 * index * 392}]} >
                <SvgUri uri={squidgetsContext.squidget[item.key]} />
              </View>
            }
          />
      </View>
```

And the styling

```
  previewListStyle: {
    position: 'relative',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 74,
    width: 258,
    height: 392,
    top: 0,

  },
  previewItemStyle: {
    width: 258,
    height: 392
  },
```

Difference (ignore the safearea issue). The Android one shows the scrollview, then when overlayed the 2nd layer is MIA!

[image: iOS Screenshot]

[image: Android - scrolling]

[image]

Comment: N.B I've tried using an position 0 over a negative margin to no effect. Also tried setting the initialNumToRender and WindowSize to move than 2